# PostSharp: Include some classes or some methods only

Tags: c#, logging, postsharp

I need to add logging to a specific class or a specific method only.
Reading documentation [here](https://doc.postsharp.net/add-logging) and [here](https://doc.postsharp.net/attribute-multicasting) I cannot find a way to reach my goal.

Listed below are my test cases.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1.C1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int Method1()
        {
            return 42;
        }    
    } 
}

namespace ClassLibrary1.C2
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public int Method1()
        {
            return 42 * 2;
        }     
    }

    public class Class3
    {
        public int Method1()
        {
            return 42 * 2;
        }     

        public int Method2()
        {
            return 42 * 3;
        }     

    }
}
```

AssemblyInfo content

```
using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;
using PostSharp.Extensibility;

[assembly: Log(AttributePriority = 1, AttributeExclude = true, AttributeTargetTypes = "ClassLibrary1.*")]
[assembly: Log(AttributePriority = 2, AttributeExclude = false, AttributeTargetTypes = "ClassLibrary1.C2*")]
```

In this way, I'm able to exclude the whole Class1 from the log, but only because it belongs to a different namespace.

How can I include *Class3.Method2()* only to the logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post my solution using AttributeTargetMembers

```
using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;
using PostSharp.Extensibility;

[assembly: Log(AttributePriority = 1, AttributeExclude = true, AttributeTargetMembers="Method1")]    
[assembly: Log(AttributePriority = 2, AttributeExclude = false, AttributeTargetMembers="Method2")]
[assembly: Log(AttributePriority = 3, AttributeExclude = true, AttributeTargetTypes = "ClassLibrary1.C1*")]
[assembly: Log(AttributePriority = 4, AttributeExclude = true, AttributeTargetTypes = "ClassLibrary1.C2.Class2")]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @ilCosmico is correct. Another way to include a specific member is to add a `[Log]` attribute to the member declaration. For example:

```
...

namespace ClassLibrary1.C2
{
    ...

    public class Class3
    {
        ...

        [Log]
        public int Method2()
        {
            return 42 * 3;
        }     

    }
}
```